# Replacing characters in string during loop in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, loops, plpgsql

In several languages you can do something like:

1. Declare a variable of string type
2. Make a loop from 0 to 4
3. During each iteration you can select and also set a specific character of the string

In php:

```
$str = '';
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
$str .= $i;
}
```

In javascript:

```
var str = '';
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
str += i;
}
```

In both the cases above the variable "str" will contain the string "01234"

Well, can you do the same in plpgsql

I have seen that there are both text[] and varchar[]. 
And also a lot of string functions. Maybe rpad could help in accomplishng this?

WHat I have tried is the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
RETURNS varchar[] AS $str$
declare str varchar[];
BEGIN
for x in 0..4
loop
str[x] := '_';
end loop;
return str;
END;
$str$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But the result of the call is:

```
[0:4]={_,_,_,_,_}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to do the same thing I do in php/js even in postgres?

Comment: You are returning an array not a string (varchar), so the output is to be expected. What exactly are you trying to do? `varchar[]` is an array of strings not an array of characters.

Comment: I want to return a string that has been modified during a loop. 
1 - Str = '';
2 - Loop from 1 to 5;
3 - Set the X character of the string equals to the iteration counter;
4 - result: Str = '12345';

Answer (score 2):

Just as your php or JS code doesn't use arrays, plpgsql doesn't need or want arrays to build a string in a loop, the `||` concatenation operator is good enough.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() RETURNS text AS $str$
DECLARE
 str text:='';
 x int;
BEGIN
for x in 0..4
loop
  str := str || chr(ascii('0')+x);
end loop;
return str;
END;
$str$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Demo:

```
 select test();
 test  
-------
 01234
```

**UPDATE** following comments:

If `str` was pre-existing and characters should be replaced in it, use `overlay`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(str text) RETURNS text AS $str$
DECLARE
 x int;
BEGIN
for x in 0..4
loop
  str := overlay(str PLACING chr(ascii('0')+x) FROM x+1);
end loop;
return str;
END;
$str$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Demo:

```
select test('abcdefghi');
   test    
-----------
 01234fghi
```

Comment: @user1963937 As each iteration incurs an SPI call, this sure won't be efficient though. Prefer set operations, e.g. `SELECT string_agg('', x::text) FROM generate_series(0,4) x;`

Comment: Daniel: that works perfectly. However, I have to blame myself. The "str" has to be se before loop and then changed at position "x" in each iteration. Something like: str := '*****'. And then in each iteration change the character * at position x with the x itself. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there is almost always a more elegant and efficient set-based solution when working with SQL:

```
SELECT overlay('fooxxxxxxxbar' PLACING string_agg(g::text, '') FROM 4 FOR 7)
FROM   generate_series (1,4) g;
```

Result:

```
foo1234bar
```

Also demonstrating that `overlay()` can replace any length of string with any other string.

Coming from procedural languages, you have to re-think your approach with a declarative, set-based language like SQL. PL/pgSQL adds procedural elements, but a set-based approach is superior most of the time (when possible), even in PL/pgSQL.